# Tweening in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, tween

I've heard of multiple ways you can tween objects in AS3; I've heard people talking about TweenLite and TweenMax as being the solution to these kinds of problems. However, I'm lost to the whole idea, could someone please explain to me how TweenLite and TweenMax work, and the features they have? If not, could you please link to me a website that offers good information on how to use them effectively?

Comment: Going to greensocks (tweenlite) website might be a good place to start.  He has lots of examples that will give you a good idea of what can be done with his tweening library.    http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/    Scroll down to the 'interactive demo'

Comment: I second greensocks tweenmax/tween lite, so far has been very easy to use in the couple of instances I've used it, using tweenlite you get a minimial foot-print and can dynamically load only plugins/source that you need into your swf.  Greatness.

Comment: I don't do much flash these days. But when i do, I tween with Greensock. ... A kickass library to be sure. Whatever it costs, it's worth it. And if Jack couldn't kick any more butt, he recently released a JS adaptation. Rockin.

Comment: @Bosworth99 Did you use TweenLite or TweenMax? Opinions on either?

Comment: TweenMax is TweenLite plus extra features. If you don't need them, just use TweenLite. Check the site for a comprehensive list. The main benefit is simply size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be a bit careful with the Greensock products.  If you plan to use the code for commercial products, you will have to pay for the license.  And it is a yearly fee, not a one-time payment.

There are actually free options out there, including tweener (http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) and the tweening that comes with Flash/AS3.  Tweener is no longer updated, but still does the job.

Reading the docs or searching for tutorials is the clear first step.

Comment: When you say commericial, could I release something on Newgrounds/Armor Games/Addicting Games/etc.? Or would I have to pay?

Comment: The current answer would be found on Greensock's website, under the licensing terms.

Comment: Grant Skinner's GTween is also very good and has a better (free) license.  Though I don't think it's in active development anymore.

Comment: Ill look into that too, but ill probably stay with GreenSock.

Comment: GreenSock's stuff is the best/most robust. And you only need the license if you charge the end user to use the product.

Comment: @londondrugs-mediaservices, that is misleading.  It is not "only".  You can make ads and freely accessible websites, or free apps.  But people here generally will have at least a foot in the commercial apps market, and need to know that *any* commercial app/game using Greensock products will require the *yearly* fee.  Other tween options -- including the vastly improved Flash built-in tweening -- should be researched before committing to a pay-to-play system.

Comment: iND - this was in response to your answer which is also misleading as the are plenty of commercial uses that don't need the license.

Comment: Fee required:  "The code will be used in a commercial game, web site, component, or software product for which a usage/access/license/microtransaction fee is collected from multiple customers."  [Greensock licensing](http://www.greensock.com/licensing/)  Commercial uses, sure, but not if users directly pay for the app/game.  Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment, if you use Greensock in production work, you have to pay a yearly license fee.

You can accomplish all your tweening needs with the normal tweening options that come with the Flash program and/or you can also animate objects by using AS2/AS3 code.

Comment: you only need to special license if a fee is charged to your END users in your production work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GTween, which is licensed under the MIT license. I have used it before and it is good!